# Convert Atom (XML) to JSON

Tags: json, xml, converters, atom-feed

Do someone have a way to convert data from Atom (XML) format to JSON? I would prefer a free online tool to do this. I cannot post the data i am trying to convert online: As it contains sensitive information.

Comment: What format do you actually want it in?  Just saying "JSON" leaves things a bit vague, as the internal structure could be absolutely anything.

Comment: @cloudfeet I want the JSON to format after the field names and structure that are provided in the XML. Just a straight covert from Atom (XML) to JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Convert XML to JSON" is simple to say, but XML and JSON are different structural paradigms.  If your XML document looks like:

```
<a>
    <b>foo</b>
    <c prop="value">bar</c>
</a>
```

... how do you represent that in JSON?  There are lots of questions, like:

- Does ordering matter? (Object properties in JSON are unordered, so after conversion there is no way to tell if `<c>` came before or after `<b>`)
- If there is only one `<b>`, does that mean it's a single-item array, or just an object?
- How do you represent attributes?  Does the convertor flip between plain strings (for `"b"`) and objects with extra properties (for `"c"`) depending on whether attributes are defined?

Each "XML to JSON convertor" I've seen has taken a slightly different approach to this, so there is no "standard" behaviour to rely on.

So, for a complete answer, I think you need to give a clearer idea of what you want your JSON ATOM format to look like.

---

If you just want *something*, and you'll work around whatever you get, then you might be able to do this with a service like Yahoo Pipes (example [here](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=DJEg41Ac3BG8IAI2E5PZnA), I'm sure there are more).

However, you are at the whim of whatever actual convertor is being used behind the scenes, which might have odd behaviours (e.g. one day your source feed adds an attribute, and your output changes dramatically).

Comment: To reduce ambiguity such translator should check XML's Schema/DTD.

Answer (score 1):

We found an XSLT here:

http://www.bjelic.net/2012/08/01/coding/convert-xml-to-json-using-xslt/#code

and slightly modified it to handle the links & categories elements of Atom Document to the way we want to show it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*[node()]">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="detect" />
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="detect">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current()) and name(following-sibling::*[1]) != name(current())">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*[name() != name(current())]) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current())">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
                    <xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*) = name(current())">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][name() = name(current())]">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>" : [</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" /><xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(./child::*) > 0 or count(@*) > 0">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(./child::*) = 0">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:apply-templates select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="obj-content">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="attr" />
            <xsl:if test="count(@*) &gt; 0 and (count(child::*) &gt; 0 or text())">, </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" mode="detect" />
            <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and not(@*)">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and @*">
                <xsl:text>"text" : "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">, </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="attr">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node/@TEXT | text()" name="removeBreaks">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, '&#xA;'))"><xsl:copy-of select="$pText"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($pText, '&#xD;&#xA;'), ' ')"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="removeBreaks">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '&#xD;&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Cheers for giving the URL to my blog as well ;)

Comment: @BojanBjelic, your welcome! :-) That XSLT is quite useful for us.